# perform Reducer operation in Mapper Class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

in my mapper class i read the file line by line and perform some string operation on each line (i.e remove special characters from string) after that in reducer each line is stored in a new file.

Basically my reducer only create the file and write each line on new file nothing else so is that possible that my mapper creates the files rather than passing data to reducer. It means that I don't want the reducer and perform its operation in mapper.
I don't know much about Mapreduce so any type of help would be appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you want is very much possible, what you need is a map only job. i.e a job which only  a mapper but no reducer.

The way you can achieve it is by setting the number of reducers to 0 in your driver class.

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

A more detailed blog on this topic can be found [here](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/05/map-only-jobs-in-hadoop.html)

To generate a file per input line Consider using the hdfs api directly from your mapper namely [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) and [FileStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html)

Comment: but how I am suppose to create multiple out files as I want to write each line on a new file. I don't want to perform any sorting operation. I am using `LazyOutputFormat`...

Comment: Why do you have such a requirement ?, Consider using the hdfs api directly from your mapper namely [FileSystem](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) and [FileStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html)

Comment: I am writing file in mapper because I am having some problem in reducer it stops after some iterations (i.e when input file has lines greater than 2000) and it does not create any output file...

Comment: You might want to ask a new question with those details, someone should be able to help you out with that, writing a file for each line processed by the mapper is possible but not recommended, i really doubt if it will scale. Encourage you to review your design